# why dotnet nuget packages of type template can't be installed using nuget package manager

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install a nuget package of type template using nuget package manager. I keep getting error

> Package 'Auth0.Templates 2.0.0' has a package type 'Template' that is not supported by project 'ConsoleApp1'.

I m trying to do this so that my existing project gets modified as per the template inside this Nuget package. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi vikben, any update of this issue, does zivkan's answer be able to answer your question? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template packages are designed to work with the [`dotnet new` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new). I believe that once a template has been installed locally from the command line, it's also available in Visual Studio's new project wizard, but I don't think there's any GUI to install such template packages within VS, you need to use the CLI.

So, open a terminal, whether that's from Windows or even the terminal within VS. Then you can run [`dotnet new install Auth0.Templates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-install).

Then, you can create a new project using `dotnet new Auth0.WebAPI`, or any other templates they provide (the package contains 4 packages).

It's not possible to use a template (package or otherwise) to modify an existing project. What you can do is create a new project in a new directory, then open the `csproj` files side by side and copy any project definitions you want (same for other files the template might include).